# How to validate string that contain 2 restriction

Tags: xsd-validation

I need to validate string with 2 restrictions. The string length is 6. First 3 elements is between [-1000-1000] and the other 3 elements is between [-3.14 -3.14].

For example: 1000 1000 900 3 2 3.14

I've tried this:

```
<xs:complexType name="aaa">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="bb">
        <xs:attribute name="size" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>



  <xs:simpleType name="bb">
    <xs:union memberTypes="listtry listtry2 "> 
    </xs:union>
  </xs:simpleType>  

  <xs:simpleType name="listtry">
  <xs:restriction base="mytry">
    <xs:length value="6"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType> 

   <xs:simpleType name="mytry">
    <xs:list itemType="try1"></xs:list>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="try1">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
      <xs:maxInclusive value="100000"/>
      <xs:minInclusive value="-100000"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>


  <xs:simpleType name="listtry2">
  <xs:restriction base="mytry2">
    <xs:length value="6"/>
  </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType> 

  <xs:simpleType name="mytry2">
    <xs:list itemType="tryPI"> </xs:list>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="tryPI">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
      <xs:maxInclusive value="3.14"/>
      <xs:minInclusive value="-3.14"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

You can create rules for each individual value (as you have done), but their is no way to say a list of values has different validation rules for each element.

The closest I think your going to get is an regex (xs:pattern) that restricts each value. Something like this

> -?\d{1,4} -?\d{1,4} -?\d{1,4} -?\d(.\d+)? -?\d(.\d+)? -?\d(.\d+)?

(I'm not great at regex stuff, but I think this is close!)

A better approach perhaps is to break the 6 values out into separate 2 (maybe 6) element/attributes. Then you can apply the validation rules you have already. to each group of values.

I Splitting the value across 2 attributes you would get something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid Studio 2017 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Thing">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="Values3x1000" type="list3Value1000Type" />
            <xs:attribute name="Value3Pi" type="list3ValuePiType" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="value1000Type">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
            <xs:maxInclusive value="1000" />
            <xs:minInclusive value="-1000" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="listValue1000Type">
        <xs:list itemType="value1000Type" />
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="list3Value1000Type">
        <xs:restriction base="listValue1000Type">
            <xs:length value="3" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="valuePiType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
            <xs:maxInclusive value="3.14" />
            <xs:minInclusive value="-3.14" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="listValuePiType">
        <xs:list itemType="valuePiType" />
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="list3ValuePiType">
        <xs:restriction base="listValuePiType">
            <xs:length value="3" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

[image: Liquid XML Simple Types]

Comment: My solution is close to the second approach, I divided into 2 groups but the union isn't working for me.

Comment: How can I check the elements for the second element for example? To jump over the first.